# How can I enable right mouse click on my HP Stream 11

Tags: touchpad, hp

I have an HP Stream 11 and my touchpad will not accept right mouse click or click/hold/drag (like to reposition a window) any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf into
   /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
2. Add `Option "ClickPad" "true"` inside the first InputClass section.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/3cw3ei/hp_stream_11_no_right_click/)

Comment: I do not have /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ what next?

Comment: Then create it is would assume

Comment: Copy the file into the /X11 directory, then rename it

Comment: Tried, the /etc/x11/ will not allow me to create a new folder (thanks for your patience)

Comment: dont worry! However there is no need to make a folder..... you should have the X11 folder there already simply do: 
 sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
then do 
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
and add the line of code

Comment: captain@captain-HP:~$  sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
[sudo] password for captain: 
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/’: Not a directory

Comment: @TrevorClarke Thanks! It was 70-synaptics.conf for me.